# mysql count child table rows with condition

Tags: mysql, count, conditional-statements, left-join

I have two tables: "user" -> "order"

**TABLE: user**

```
user_id
-----------
    u1
    u2
```

**TABLE: order**

```
order_id | user_id | flag
-------------------------
    o1   |    u1   |  fA
    o2   |    u2   |  fB
```

***Y need obtain all users counting how many times have orders with flag 'fA'***

RESULTS WHAT I NEED:

```
user_id | orders
----------------
   u1   |   1
   u2   |   0
```

**I TRY:**

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    COUNT(o.order_id) AS orders
FROM
    `user` AS u LEFT JOIN
    `order` AS o USING (user_id)
WHERE
    o.flag IS NULL OR
    o.flag IN ('fA')
GROUP BY
    u.user_id;
```

But, this query is excluding **user=u2** because he don't have an order with flag **fA**;
I need the **user=u2** appear with **orders=0**

Maybe something like that:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    COUNT(o.order_id IF o.flag IN('fA')) OR 0 AS count ...
```

**Tables and data:**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (user_id VARCHAR(2) NULL);
CREATE TABLE `order` (order_id VARCHAR(2) NULL,user_id VARCHAR(2) NULL,flag VARCHAR(2) NULL);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES ('u1'), ('u2');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES ('o1','u1','fA'),('o2','u2','fB');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try using the condition in the 'ON' statement of the 'LEFT JOIN', like this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, COUNT(o.user_id)
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN `order` o ON u.user_id = o.user_id AND o.flag = 'fA'
GROUP BY user_id
```

[Runing example in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79b3b/4)

Answer (score 5):

There are at least three ways to do it:

1. Just use dependent subquery.

   ```
   SELECT u.user_id, (SELECT count(user_id) FROM `order` o WHERE o.user_id = u.user_id AND o.flag = 'fA') count
   FROM `user` u;
   ```
2. Use `LEFT JOIN` on subquery:

   ```
   SELECT u.user_id, count(o.user_id) count
   FROM `user` u
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id FROM `order` WHERE flag = 'fA') o USING (user_id)
   GROUP BY u.user_id;
   ```
3. Use `LEFT JOIN` on combined condition:

   ```
   SELECT u.user_id, count(o.user_id) count
   FROM `user` u
   LEFT JOIN `order` o ON o.user_id = u.user_id AND o.flag = 'fA'
   GROUP BY u.user_id;
   ```

The fastest is last I think, but it need to be tested on large enough data and see execution plan.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c55dd/35)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a left outer join instead of left join

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    COUNT(o.order_id) AS orders
FROM
    `user` AS u LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `order` AS o USING (user_id)
WHERE
    o.flag IS NULL OR
    o.flag IN ('fA')
GROUP BY
    u.user_id;
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to use OUTER JOINs, find out more about it, thanks for introducing me

Comment: Why is this answer has most upvotes? `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are the same. They are aliases of each other. So this answer is just wrong. Other answers are good still.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a CASE statement.  I don't have MYSQL here today so I can validate the syntax, but it should be close to this:

```
  SELECT   u.user_id,
             CASE
                WHEN (SELECT COUNT (*)
                        FROM ORDER z
                       WHERE z.user_id = USER.user_id) > 0
                   THEN COUNT (*)
                ELSE 0
             END CASE AS cnt
        FROM USER
    GROUP BY USER.user_id;
```

Comment: Actually, it is not required to use `CASE` here because `SELECT COUNT (*)` already returns `0` if no records found. `GROUP BY` is also unnecessary here as `user_id` is obviously a PK. So it can be simplified to `SELECT u.user_id, (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM ORDER z WHERE z.user_id = USER.user_id) cnt FROM USER`.

Answer (score 1):

This query will work:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    COUNT(o.order_id) AS orders
FROM
    `user` AS u LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT user_id, order_id FROM `order` WHERE flag IS NULL OR flag IN ('fA')) as o
    USING (user_id)
GROUP BY
    u.user_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works good; but, is necesary to use LEFT OUTER JOIN?, because with simple LEFT JOIN works fine.
This is additional: Is there a way to do with simple SELECT query without sub-selects?

Comment: I'm using LEFT OUTER JOIN in case there is a user that has no entries in the order table yet. Is there a reason why you don't prefer a sub-query solution?

Comment: Well, I wrote my little db abstraction layer for php, work this way:
$users = new users();
$results = $user->select(array(
//another parameters...
'JOIN' => 'array_key_where_previosly_i_defined_join_rules,another_key'
));
The parameter 'JOIN' just accept simple 'keys' with additional ALIAS and 'LEFT','RIGHT' modificators, no accept a customo SELECT as a table. (Example: 'JOIN'=>'LEFT:key,RIGHT:key AS alias').

But I think y solve de problem, I create a "view" with custom select join, and now I can create a key for this "view table".

I'm not sure to diferentiate LEFT [OUTER] JOIN. Thanks again

Comment: Lets see, if I add another user "u3" and this user don't have a row in order table. The querys "LEFT JOIN" and "LEFT OUTER JOIN" returns the same correct result. :S

Comment: I'm glad the solution works. About outer of inner join you can refer to the documentation for more details http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html